# CacheManager.Net - Redis pipelining

Tags: caching, redis, cachemanager

Can someone please confirm whether CacheManager.Net supports redis pipelining?

I could not find it in the [documentation](http://cachemanager.michaco.net/Documentation/Index/cachemanager_architecture)

Thanks a lot.

Cheers,
U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of.
CacheManager does not have support any batch operations directly.

But in case of Redis you can use `cache.Put` which internally uses the fire and forget flag of StackExchange.Redis. This is one kind of pipelining as the client doesn't wait for one operation to complete before you can excecute the next one.

If you use `cache.Add` (or Update and such) instead, CacheManager has to wait for the reply, e.g. if the operation was successful or not, maybe the item did exist already etc...

So, if you just want to push a lot of data into the cache, use Put.